# rails dynamic selection from list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, dynamic

i need to change content depending which items is chosen. I am pretty new to rails and cant figure out how to do this. I know i need to use ajax, i guess! Okey.

Here is the list

```
 <div class="table_wrap city_list_wrap">
    <table class="city_list table normal">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3"> City list </th>
          </tr>
          <% @cities.each_slice(3) do | slice | %>
            <tr>
              <% slice.each do |city| %>
                <td class="city_tab"><%= city.title %> (<%= city.car_dealers_count %>) </td>
              <% end %>
            <tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

And what after i push on one of the cities u need to show the list of that city items in table like this:

```
<div class="table_wrap">
    <table class="table normal clickable" id="item_table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:30%"><%= t("public.item.title") %></th>
          <th style="width:45%"><%= t("public.item.info") %> </th>
          <th style="width:25%"><%= t("public.item.logo") %> </th>
        </tr>
        <% city_title = "" %>
        <% @items.each do | item | %>
        <% unless city_title == item.city.title %>
          <% city_title = item.city.title %>
          <tr class="caption"><td colspan="3"><%= city_title %></td></tr>
        <% end %>
        <tr id="item-<%= item.id %>" class="hoverable">
          <td><%= item.title %></td>
          <td>
            <p>
              <%= item.address %><br><%= item.phone_number %><br/><%= link_to item.site, "http://#{item.site}", target:"_blank", rel: "nofollow", class: "item-link" if item.site.present? %>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td><%= image_tag item.small_logo, alt: item.title %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

At the start this list is shown and all items are shown. After i click on one of the cities i need to show only items from that city in this second table.. How to do this? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey i did this pretty simple way gave every city field id its id and rows with city items that id too. and after click `$("id").hide() or show()` depending on situation

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem: https://github.com/innku/metropoli

Read the helper, it's real easy to install.

Comment: i already have this information in my database. all i need to know is how to show it when specific city is chosen.

Comment: Use like on https://github.com/innku/metropoli/blob/master/test/test_app/app/views/home/index.html.erb
The autocomplete will restart the list for select with ajax.

If you want to know how, look on https://github.com/innku/metropoli/blob/master/test/test_app/public/javascripts/metropoli.jquery.ui.js